# Opencv: how to draw a rotated bounding box in python

Tags: python, opencv

I am currently doing a project on painting recognition using opencv-python.
Right now I am able to detect most of the paintings decently however the bounding boxes are rectangles that include a lot of background.
This is because the cv2.boundingRect() function finds the bounding rectangle with a perpendicular projection (afaik). However I want to find the best bounding box without detecting any background.

The main part of my code:

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

hue, saturation, value = cv2.split(hsv)
blurred_sat = cv2.GaussianBlur(saturation, (5, 5), 0)
edges = cv2.Canny(blurred_sat, 45, 100)

kernel = np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8)
dilate = cv2.dilate(edges, kernel, iterations=6)
erode = cv2.erode(dilate, kernel, iterations=2)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(erode, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

contours = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)[:10]

# cv2.drawContours(frame, contours, -1, (255, 255, 0), 3)
for contour in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
    if area >= 3000:
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
        subImg = frame[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        cv2.rectangle(frame,
                      (x, y), (x + w, y + h),
                      (0, 255, 0),
                      2)
```

[Current output image (video)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcRF2.png)
[Desired output image with desired bounding box in red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzUjS.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After finding and sorting the contours, you need to use `cv2.minAreaRect()` function. This draws a rectangle enclosing each contour with the least area:

```
import numpy as np

# portion of code to find and sort contours

for contour in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
    if area >= 3000:
        rect = cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)
        box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
        box = np.int0(box)
        cv2.drawContours(frame, [box], 0, (0, 255, 0), 2)
```

***Note:*** `cv2.minAreaRect()` returns properties of the rotated rectangle (center, dimensions and angle of rotation). `cv2.boxPoints()` is used to obtain the vertices of the rectangle. This is then passed into `cv2.drawContours()` to draw them.

Have a look at [the documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html)

For details on the algorithm:

- [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62083411/minimum-bounding-rectangle-of-polygon)
- [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542855/algorithm-to-find-the-minimum-area-rectangle-for-given-points-in-order-to-comput)

**Update:**

The following code approximates a quadrilateral around a contour and draws it on `frame`. The variable `value` determines how strong you want your approximations to be:

```
# use a value between 0 and 1
value = 0.02
for c in contours:
    perimeter = cv2.arcLength(c, True)  
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, value*perimeter, True)    
    if len(approx) == 4:
        cv2.drawContours(frame, [approx], 0, (0, 0, 255), 5)
```

Comment: Doesn't this solution still use a rectangle though? I would like to find the best bounding box (which is often not a rectangle but a quadrilateral.
In the pictures I included this is seen when I drew the red desired bounding boxes, they aren't rectangles.

Comment: @f.vdv check out the updated code, to draw approximate quadrilaterals